# Why are some functions global and others part of an object?

Tags: javascript

I've just explored one big proprietary project and I found one interesting moment:
In one cases the author uses functions as part of an object (the object matches corresponding HTML page):

```
PageObject = {
    inlineFunctions: function () {
       //Some code
    };
}
```

In other cases the author used separate functions in the same js file:

```
function separateFunction() {
    //Some code
}
```

I don't have an opportunity to ask the author. I suppose it's some common code pattern.
Can anybody explain it?

Comment: It's called the "module pattern", a.k.a. "namespaces". And its purpose is solely to structure your code.

Comment: `PageObject` also has access to a `this` variable.  `separateFunction` has no implicitly bound `this`.

Comment: So my separate functions is private functions (or something like this because I propose you can call it from anywhere)?

Comment: Think of `PageObject` as a class.

Comment: Modularity is generally used to avoid polluting global space

Comment: Nothing in either of those patterns is private julia.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Both could be the same in matters of functionality but their scope and way of calling them may change.

- **Function inside an object**.  These functions can be used to define a
  structure, for example this object person:

```
    var person = {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        getFullName: function () {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it is actually part of the object. Some consideration you should to have here is that if you define the function like this you need to reference the parent object and this function will exist as long as the parent exists.

```
    person.getFullName();
```

- **Global functions**. On the other hand, the global functions can be defined independent to any parent object and can be called from anywhere within you code. For example:

```
    function getParameters(){
        //Implementation to get parameters
    }
```

Some things to consider here, you have to be sure that you are not overwriting any other global function and also you should be sure this is really a global function that is going to be needed in the entire application, otherwise you should consider creating a utility class with your functions which you could create and remove as needed optimizing the memory usage and avoiding losing the global functions in your code.